# How do I use a custom xml entity in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox-addon, entity

I have an 'overlay.dtd' file with a line like `<!ENTITY myentity "myvalue">`.

At the top of my xul file I have `<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM 'chrome://myaddon/locale/overlay.dtd'>`.
In my xul file, I have `<script src='myscript.js'>`.

I want to know if there is any way to access 'myentity' from the script. 
`alert("&myentity;")` just alerts "&myentity;"

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/stringbundle (an alternate way of externalizing strings)

Answer (score 0):

Entities are handled in the XML parser. This means you can only refer to entities in XML files. So I assume that rewriting your example to something like the following would work.

In your xul file:

```
<script>
var myentity = "&myentity;";
</script>
<script src='myscript.js'>
```

In your myscript.js:

```
alert(myentity);
```

But... for scripting convenience XUL may treat `<script>` differently, which would break entity resolving.